# My emulator date input type has a forward slash (/), my device does not?

Tags: android, date

**Problem:** My emulator date input type has a forward slash and numbers (/), my device does not?

I'm not sure what to try on this, except I had to create a workaround which involved using a text field with an `android:digits="0123456789/" constraint. Any thoughts on the reason why?

The physical device is a Samsung A32 5G it has numbers only and no '/' and the emulator does.

... was this ...

```
android:inputType="date"
```

... now this ...

```
android:inputType="text"
android:digits="@string/allowDateCharacters"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem: My emulator date input type has a forward slash and numbers (/), my device does not?

This is not a problem.

There are ~3 billion Android devices in use, across tens of thousands of device models. There are dozens of soft keyboards ("input method editors") that ship pre-installed on those device models, and there are dozens more that those billions of users can install from the Play Store and elsewhere.

What keys a soft keyboard offers for a given `android:inputType` is up to the developers of the soft keyboard — it is not up to you or I. Consider
`android:inputType` to be a suggestion, not a command.

Comment: OK, great, that makes sense. I suspected as much but just wasn't sure if it was an issue a combination of parameters needed. Again, thanks!